# Stop magnifying screen on wheelscroll

Tags: chromium, mouse-scroll

Is there a way to prevent wheel scroll from messing with screen ? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 and Chromium and often what happens is that when I try to scroll down or up zooming is triggered and the browser shrinks or magnifies the screen.

Very annoying bug.

Comment: The mouse wheel should only affect zoom if you scroll while holding down the CTRL key. Might that one be stuck or accidentally pressed maybe?

Comment: I'm aware of this functionality. When I hit CTRL and scroll the wheel web browser should zoom in or out depending on the direction of the scroll. But it is doing without me even touching CTRL. I was hoping there's some hack for this.

Comment: i have heard some program don't play nice with regard to whether CTRL is down when handling mouse wheel roll.  i guess Chromium is one of those.  yet another reason for me to stick with Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a `terminal` window and type the <kbd>c</kbd> key by itself. Does it show `c` or `^c` in the terminal window?

If it shows `^c` then you've got a stuck <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key on your keyboard, or a defective keyboard.

**Update #1:**

Firefox was installed and doesn't exhibit the problem. The problem is with Chromium or its settings.

Comment: Nope .... when I press 'c' only the letter shows up.

Comment: Does the problem only occur in Chromium?

Comment: That's a good question. Let me install Firefox and let me get back to you later.  :)

Comment: Well .... I installed Firefox and gave it a test drive .... it appears to be affecting my Chromium installation only. Firefox's behaving fine.  :/

Comment: @MarkAlexa you could try uninstalling, then reinstalling Chromium... or install Chrome, and see if either fix the problem.

Comment: Way ahead of ya  :)  Will see how that goes. I'll mark your answer as 'Accepted' since your original solution was completely valid. It didn't necessarily solved the problem but you expressed interest in this particular problem and I appreciate it.  :)

Comment: @MarkAlexa keep me posted on what you find :-)